# How can I pull an env variable into VIM key mapping?

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts, environment-variables

I have the following [F3] key mapping defined in my .vimrc. This inserts a line of text into my file containing the current date such as `2012-01-20`. It works in command or insert mode. How can I include an environment variable such as $LOGNAME or $HOME in this line so the output is something like `2012-01-20 - user123 -`? Have tried variations of `<C-R>=$LOGNAME<CR>` however this only seems to work for the `inoremap` line.

```
nnoremap <F3> "=strftime("%Y-%m-%d")<CR>P
inoremap <F3> <C-R>=strftime("%Y-%m-%d")<CR>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
nnoremap <F3> "=strftime("%Y-%m-%d").' - '.$LOGNAME<CR>P
inoremap <F3> <C-R>=strftime("%Y-%m-%d").' - '.$LOGNAME<CR>
```